OSX M1 - Grease Pencil - constant 50-90% GPU usage
Kinda new to the whole Grease Pencil thing. Noticed slight Lag while drawing with the default brushes. Changing input samples to 0 gets me better results but the GPU is still hovering about 50 - 90% usage. Anyone has some ideas on how to lower that amount or is it normal? Maybe I need to update the OS...
Macbook Pro
Monterey 12.3
M1 Pro
Memory 16GB
Cores 10 (8 performance and 2 efficiency)

I haven't played often enough with GP to encounter any lag. That being said, 90% GPU usage isn't abnormal on itself and shouldn't cause lag, 100 would. Are you sure you aren't hitting a bottleneck somewhere else? Have you tried GP on a new default scene to be sure it doesn't come from your project instead?

Good point! Default GP project is around 60%. Maybe the rather high usage is because I had a bunch of Objects with multiple materials and layers in the project. I was checking with a fellow GP animator and his Mac Studio M2 was around 40 - 50%.
